# Netty HttpObjectAggregator with Http2

Tags: netty, http2

I'm building an Http2 server with Netty 4.1 (and the server will only need to support Http2 clients).  For my most simple request handling, I want to have the full Http2 request (i.e., `FullHttpRequest`) before performing any business logic.

How can I do this with Http2?  Netty's `HttpObjectAggregator` only seems intended for Http1.

Comment: First off, check here: http://netty.io/wiki/requirements-for-4.x.html

Says you need an additional component for http/2 support

Comment: I don't see this mentioning anything about Http2 object aggregation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this you may need to use the `InboundHttp2ToHttpAdapter` in your pipeline. Please check:

- https://github.com/netty/netty/blob/4.1/codec-http2/src/main/java/io/netty/handler/codec/http2/InboundHttp2ToHttpAdapter.java
- https://github.com/netty/netty/blob/4.1/codec-http2/src/main/java/io/netty/handler/codec/http2/InboundHttp2ToHttpAdapterBuilder.java